# PHP unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a project and I keep getting this error:

> unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), expecting ')'

```
array(
  'id' => 'my-meta-box-3',
  'title' => 'Episodes',
  'pages' => array('post'), // custom post type
  'context' => 'normal',
  'priority' => 'high',
  'fields' => 
    array(
      array(
        'name' => 'Tabla de descargas:',
        'id' => 'Episodes',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'desc' => '<B>Tienes que pegar el codigo html que viene 
          junto con el theme y luego pegar los links de los servidores</B>'
      ),
    )
)
```

I've tried to solve it but can't.

Answer (score 4):

Are you missing the ; at the end?
This works:

```php
$array = array(
    'id' => 'my-meta-box-3',
    'title' => 'Episodes',
    'pages' => array('post'), // custom post type
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Tabla de descargas:',
            'id' => 'Episodes',
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'desc' => 'Tienes que pegar el codigo html que viene junto con el theme y luego pegar los links de los servidores'
        )
    )
);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Not the `;` but the extra `,` on OP's 3rd last line of code.

Comment: The    ,    doesn't matter - array will still work.

Comment: sorry but it doesnt work, thanks btw!